# GWT History - Does state create History or History results in state?

Tags: java, gwt, browser-history, gwt-history

I'm a bit puzzled about the examples I find for GWT's History mechanism.

Looking and running the example [GWT History](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory#example) it doesn't seem to be very good.

History is explained often as something that results from Changes in the application.

The example has multiple problems:

- Initial state is as well the empty token and the token "page0"

  --> "History" Back shows the same page twice before "leaving the application"
- History and State are synced somehow indirect.

  - A Tab selection causes a selection event, which sets a new token. Settings the token causes a
    History Value Change, that selects the same tab again (?). That pattern is kind of mindtwisting.

Would it be so wrong to look at the problem from another perspective?

I think it would be much more cleaner to always change the state according to the history token.

In that case `ValueChange` would implement the "state rendering". A Button that wants to change state wouldn't do it directly but using the `History.newItem()` method, and change the state indirectly using the `valueChange` method.

e.g.

```java
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    String token = event.getValue();
    if(token.isEmpty()){
        show("welcome");
    }else if(token.equals("registration")){
        show(token);
    }
}
```

And a button that wants to display registration:

```java
welcome = new Button("Registration", new ClickHandler() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            History.newItem("registration");                
        }
    });
```

This is somehow using history to drive the applications state.

What's wrong about that, why is it done the other way around everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT History does offer a way to set the token [without causing the on history changed method to be called](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#newItem%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)  `History.newItem("registration", false);`

As for your suggestion specifically about GWT History alone, ValueChange would implement the "state rendering", that would not work in cases where you need to pass more than a String to set the state.  In such a case, I set a token as above and then use MVC to forward whatever data is needed to the view for rendering.

In any case, I definitely do not go through onValueChange in order to select a tab.  I use rather something like `tabPanel.selectTab(tabNum);`

FWIW, The current state of GWT thinking moved from just history to using [Activities and Places](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces)

You may want to see that as perhaps it better aligns with what you are trying to do.